# Ef migration Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to mirate my dbContext class , but I got this error :

```
System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'UserType' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserTypes' is based on type 'UserType' that has no keys defined.
```

here is my DbContext :

```
namespace seraydar.Models
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my class:

```
public class UserType
    {
        [Key]
        int id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name can not be longer than 30 characters."), Display(Name = "User Type")]
        string userType { get; set; }
    }
```

I just got confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Entity Framework only looks at public properties. Your properties aren't public, so they are ignored. 
The easiest way to fix this is to make them public:

```
public class UserType
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name can not be longer than 30 characters."), Display(Name = "User Type")]
    public string userType { get; set; }
}
```

Migrations will then work properly.